# How to update a xml file without losing the style xsl?

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have this xml data from url:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/style.xsl"?>
....etc...
```

I added the second line that allows me to view it in HTML format (style.xsl). But with each update, the second line disappears, how can I solve?

Example of style.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
ect...
```

Comment: What sort of update is it - xsl transform - a file rewrite?

Comment: I take information through url of the xml file. Xsl file shall print it and customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is vague on details, so your answers are going to have to be correspondingly vague.

The process performing the update is not preserving the xml-stylesheet processing instruction.  If that process is performed by an XSLT stylesheet, you need to add a template along the following lines:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>
```

If the update is being performed by some other process, you must make the analogous change to that process.